# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/6315).

Answer (score 20):

[image: Programmers Community Blog]

Answer (score 19):

[image: Code Review Stack Exchange. Tough questions, smart answers.]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Programming Puzzles and Code Golf]

Comment: This Code Golf ad is from [a promotion on our meta site.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1356/3808) [Here is its counterpart ad](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6574/100175).

Answer (score 12):

[image: Cryptography Stack Exchange]

Comment: This ad seems little misleading to me. It give an impression of links to tutorial on Cryptography

Comment: @VarunAgw related on their meta - [Is asking about the crypto community advertisement on topic?](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/417/is-asking-about-the-crypto-community-advertisement-on-topic)

Answer (score 11):

[image: How to be a Programmer by Robert L. Read]

Comment: The source for this is a svg image that I built with inkscape and can be found on the gist: [97ae06564ad50ee77dce](https://gist.github.com/shagie/97ae06564ad50ee77dce)

Comment: I'd like to have the color changed a little bit. E.g. see http://i.imgur.com/YM2K7Gt.png

Comment: @9000 I like the green too - it was a consideration when I was designing the image.  I just happen to have more fond memories of amber screens than green screens.  When the 2015 advertisements come around, I would be very interested to have the two run side by side (so to speak) and see which one [gets more clicks](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/ads/display/6315).

Comment: @9000 btw, you should submit a suggestion with your new image.  Last year there was a hat for a new community advertisement getting approved.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Debian -- The Universal Operating System]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Programming Puzzles and Code Golf]

Comment: This Code Golf ad is from [a promotion on our meta site.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1356/3808) [Here is its counterpart ad](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6575/100175).

Answer (score 9):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Answer (score 9):

[Bountied questions on Programmers.SE http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/programmers.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is a dynamic image that *does* size correctly when used.  It is based off of the referring page on Stack Exchange and fetches the featured question information.  See [physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5296/) or [apple](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884) for other examples that uses the same information and how it works.

Answer (score 8):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Git — fast and easy branching]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Software Recommendations Stack Exchange - finding the tool for you]

Comment: This advertisement is borrowed from the SuperUser - software rec meta site for the question/add : http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/876/advertisement-posted-to-super-user-please-upvote-it-there

Answer (score 7):

[image: Undo, Redo, REVIEW]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Git — fast version control]

Comment: From a recent Git convert, having moved off SVN for my personal college files.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Beat Jon Skeet]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Last year people recommended that humans should tweet things and we should advert those people instead of this bot.

Answer (score 4):

[image: ShareLaTeX]

Answer (score 3):

[image: PL and compilers on cs.se]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

(Color variation of https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6935/11732)

Comment: Gotta go all l33t with the green now, don'cha... :-)

Answer (score 1):

[image: writeLaTeX.com - Free online collaborative LaTeX editor with Integrated Rapid Preview]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Event Planning]

Answer (score -1):

[image: BXR.SU — Super User's BSD Cross Reference — BSD Source Code Search Engine over FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFly BSD kernel and userland source trees, based on OpenGrok, powered by nginx and regular expressions]

Answer (score -2):

[image: mdoc.su — short manual page URLs, a deterministic URL shortener for BSD manual pages, written in nginx.conf]

Answer (score -2):

[image: BXR.SU — Super User's BSD Cross Reference — BSD Source Code Search Engine, over FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFly BSD source trees, based on OpenGrok, powered by nginx, it is uber fast and has very short URLs.]

Answer (score -2):

[image: Question closing feed]

Comment: This is epically funny, but not quite the message we want to send.

Answer (score -2):

[image: BXR.SU — Super User's BSD Cross Reference — BSD Source Code Search Engine over FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFly BSD kernel and userland source trees, based on OpenGrok, powered by nginx and regular expressions. BSD is Dying. Seeking Kernel and Userland Developers to Hack and Improve BSD UNIX. Qualifications: C (required), asm (a plus). No prior open-source experience necessary. Warning: it's not for the faint of heart!]

Answer (score -3):

[image: {OpenGrok — System startup; initialise the world, create process 0, mount root filesystem and fork to create init and pagedaemon. kern/init_main.c::mi_startup()]

Answer (score -3):

[image: Teckids e.V. – Erkunden, Entdecken, Erfinden – Discover, Explore, Forge]